Unable to start ST-LINK GDB server / debug STM32 Board in vscode
OS: Windows 11
Board: STM32F407VG
I'm following Marc Goodner's blog on importing ST projects into vscode using the Microsoft Embedded Tools extension. I got it to work (build and debug). After a couple weeks, I updated the STM32CubeIDE to 1.17 and imported one of my projects to VScode. The project built on VScode, but whenever I start debugging I get this error message: Unable to start debugging. Debug server process failed to initialize. I have updated the ST-Link firmware, but it didn't help.
Debug Console output:
1: (133) ->
1: (138) ->
1: (138) ->STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 7.9.0
1: (138) ->Copyright (c) 2024, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.
1: (138) ->
1: (138) ->Starting server with the following options:
1: (138) ->        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
1: (138) ->        Logging Level              : 1
1: (138) ->        Listen Port Number         : 3333
1: (138) ->        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
1: (139) ->        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
1: (139) ->        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
1: (139) ->
1: (175) ->Waiting for debugger connection...
1: (10129) <-logout
1: (10139) Send Event AD7MessageEvent

Launch.json:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "${command:vscode-embedded.st.gdb}",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:3333",
      "debugServerPath": "${command:vscode-embedded.st.gdbserver}",
      "debugServerArgs": "--stm32cubeprogrammer-path ${command:vscode-embedded.st.cubeprogrammer} --swd --port-number 3333",
      "serverStarted": "Waiting for connection on port .*\\.\\.\\.",
      "stopAtConnect": true,
      "postRemoteConnectCommands": [
        {
          "text": "load build/debug/build/002LED.elf"
        }
      ],
      "logging": {
        "engineLogging": true
      },
      "preLaunchTask": "Build",
      "svdPath": "${command:vscode-embedded.st.svd}/STM32F407.svd"
    }
  ]
}

